# Why the required Startup class does't need to implement an appropriate interface, like IStartup?

Tags: c#, owin, katana

Using katana, why does the ***Startup*** class should not implement a respective interface, like for example:

```
interface IStartup
{
  void Configuration(IAppBuilder app);
}

public class MyStartup : IStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I think that it could be much more intuitive for the developers to understand what they should provide with to the `WebApp.Start<T>` method as the T argument instead of guessing and looking for examples, it should be more explicit:

```
public void Start<T>() where T : IStartup
```

Comment: Is there ever more than one Startup class?  Isn't the method that you're implementing the same anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, could be more than 1 Startup class, for example, when I'm unit-testing and need some mock server.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you run into the following code `WebApp.Start<T>`, how could you figure out what the required `T` should be without looking at docs and examples?

Comment: How is an interface going to tell you what `T` is?

Comment: You can use T argument constraints (`where`).

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how that is different from simply having the same constraints on the actual implementation method.

Comment: Now I'm having trouble figuring out what you meant, an answer with example will be perfect.

Comment: What prevents you from doing exactly the same thing you propose, but without using an interface?  **Assumption:** interfaces are often overused: prove that you need it.

Comment: It turns out that I'm not a lone ranger at this field: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24935092/952310

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63060/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-yair-nevet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is "there's NO GOOD reason". Interfaces exist to communicate structure and purpose to an implementer (abstract classes do this as well, along with providing some minimal behavior). Without them, we're left with convention. In this case, by not constraining TStartup, OWIN is allowing you to use any nonsense Startup class and can only tell you at runtime if it will work. For example:

```
WebApp.Start<string>(BaseAddress);
```

This compiles fine but throws an EntryPointNotFoundException at runtime (No 'Configuration' method was found in class 'System.String).

Not to get all philosophical, but I see this as a general trend in computing today. REST, with it's no contracts, no guarantees, you figure it out paradigm is in; SOAP is out. In some ways this is a good thing, but I don't think this example is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for answer and sorry for the late response.

Comment: This does allow OWIN to be extended in the future without breaking existing code. The only way to do that with interfaces is to version them which also has pros and cons.

Comment: This looks like golang interfaces philosophy: no class implements any interface explicitly, but rather if a class corresponds to some interface, then the class automatically implements it